# I need to compare different image values after they've been clicked

Tags: java, javafx, imageview, listener, conditional-statements

I have not been able to find any good questions regarding my predicament. I am trying to count/check how many times a specific item is clicked via an actionListener but am unsure of how to use an actionListener/EventHandler to document the click. This is being done in JavaFX.Pardon the potentially noobish question.

```
        correctUrl = getCorrectUrl(); //Correct image for set
        wrongUrl = getWrongUrl();
        initialPos(); //everything is placed into default.

       imageOne.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, event -> {
           imageOne.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent e) -> {
               imageOne = flipToCard(imageOne, 1);
           });
            returnCardOne();
            System.out.println("Tile pressed ");
            event.consume();
        });
```

The ultimate goal of the code is to notice two images have been clicked and then check to see if their URL == each-other.

Comment: I think you need to elaborate your question a bit more. For example, there's no information on how those URLs are correlated to the images.

Comment: Registering a listener like this is usually a bad idea. The first time you click `imageOne` a new event handler is set. Starting with the second click ***both*** event handlers are executed. I don't see a reason why this would be the desired effect.

Comment: The Urls are the strings for each image location my apologies i accidentally added them.

Answer (score 0):

If the `URLs` are equal, the `Images` should be equal. So why not compare `Images`? This little app demos what you are trying to achieve. Comments in the code.

> Main:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 *
 * @author Sedrick
 */
public class JavaFXApplication51 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {   
        List<ImageViewTile> imageViews = new ArrayList();
        List<ImageViewTile> cardsBeingMatched = new ArrayList();//Used to keep up with the current two cards that are pressed inorder to deteremine if they are a match
        Image initialImage = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("cardBack_blue1.png"));
        Image ace = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("cardSpadesA.png"));
        Image king = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("cardSpadesK.png"));
        imageViews.add(new ImageViewTile(initialImage, ace));
        imageViews.add(new ImageViewTile(initialImage, king));
        imageViews.add(new ImageViewTile(initialImage, ace));
        imageViews.add(new ImageViewTile(initialImage, king));

        for(ImageViewTile view : imageViews)
        {
            //Set ImageViews' onMouseClicked handler
            view.setOnMouseClicked(event->{

                if(!view.isShowing())//If card face value is not showing 
                {
                    view.showFrontImage();//show it.
                    cardsBeingMatched.add(view);//Add card being clicked to list so it can be compared against the next card
                    if(cardsBeingMatched.size() == 2)//Once two cards are in the list, see if they are equal.
                    {
                        if(cardsBeingMatched.get(0).getImage().equals(cardsBeingMatched.get(1).getImage()))//If cards are equal a match is found
                        {
                            System.out.println("Match");
                            cardsBeingMatched.clear();//clear the list to prepare to compare the next two cards that are clicked
                        }
                        else//If cards are not equal
                        {
                            System.out.println("No match");
                            //wait half a second and flip cards back over
                            Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(.5), (event1) -> {
                                System.out.println(".5 seconds need to pass before another mouse click!");
                            }));
                            timeline.setCycleCount(1);
                            timeline.play();
                            timeline.setOnFinished(event1->{
                                cardsBeingMatched.get(0).showBackImage();
                                cardsBeingMatched.get(1).showBackImage(); 
                                cardsBeingMatched.clear();//clear the list to prepare to compare the next two cards that are clicked
                            });                      
                        }
                    }                        
                }                
            });
        }

        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        for(int i = 0; i < imageViews.size(); i++)
        {
            root.add(imageViews.get(i), i % 2, i  / 2);//Add ImageViews to the GridPane
        }


        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 280, 380);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

> ImageViewTitle Class:

```
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

/**
 *
 * @author Sedrick
 */
public final class ImageViewTile extends  ImageView{
    private boolean showing;
    private final Image backImage;
    private final Image frontImage;

    public ImageViewTile(Image backImage, Image frontImage) {
        this.backImage = backImage;
        this.frontImage = frontImage;

        this.setImage(backImage);
        showing = false;
    }

    public void showBackImage()
    {
        this.setImage(backImage);
        showing = false;
    }

    public void showFrontImage()
    {
        this.setImage(frontImage);
        showing = true;
    }    

    public boolean isShowing()
    {
        return showing;
    }
}
```

I created this class to help me keep up with the `ImageView's` different states.

Comment: Your code, unfortunately, isn't functioning when I'm trying to test it. :( I'll still dissect it and evaluate how I can implement it myself though.

Comment: Use 3 different Images. Put them in the same folder these two .java files are in.